# Failing to convert newlines to breaks

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to convert newlines to breaks. But for some reason I can't get this to work. I did various tests, and I know the function is being executed, and that the variable passed to the function is definitely a string. It's weird that this does not work. Since I use exactly the same function for double escaping newlines before I send it to the server. I have tried a lot of things, and do not understand why this does not work.

```
console.log(ev);
var parsedJSON = JSON.parse(ev.data);
console.log('string that goes in function:' + parsedJSON.message);
//typeof(parsedJSON.message); string
var bericht = placeBreaks(parsedJSON.message);
    function placeBreaks(str)  {
        return str.replace(/\r?\n/g, "<br />");
    }
    console.log('string being returned: ' + bericht);
```

json: { "date": 1431199838, "name": "Root", "message": "test\ntest"}

(index):167 string that goes in function:test\ntest

(index):173 placeBreaks return: test\ntest

Comment: Your code works for me; maybe the \n is a literal, and not actually a line-break?  As in the js isn't interpreting it as a line break, but a literal backslash and an n.

Comment: It worked for me in the browser console, but only after I changed it to `\\n`, so I think @Daedalus is likely correct.

Comment: Thanks for both responding, with the information i got from you guys i can work. And get it working, however i would like to accept a answer that could explain this more indept; To why JS is actually reading this as a literal string? I was from the assumption that a string is a string. I did not know of JS parsing anthing as literal. Thx

Comment: Wow, that's really strange, it means your initial JSON did contain `\\n` - which it shouldn't. Rather check where that comes from and try to fix that.

Comment: @DDaems In order to write an answer that addresses that, we'd need(or I would at least) to see the way you generate that json in the first place.

Comment: Origenally i send: test\ntest
to the server and recieved the same line back
test\ntest, wich resulted in a json.parse stripping out the backslash:
testntest, so i double escaped it and send it to the server like:
test\\ntest, than i recieve the same string and when jsonparse has parsed it i get test\ntest.
So i though this was what i needed. But it doesn't work apperently.

Is it wrong from me handling it this way and sending a string with double escapes to the server? Also i'm still curious in why it parses it is as litteral? Is this json.parse that outputs literal strings? Ty for your replys

Comment: @DDaems It parses it as literal because you escaped it manually.  In order for it to not be parsed as literal, it has to be an actual line break; manually inserting the line break with the characters `\n` doesn't make it a line break, so to actually test it with real data, you need an actual line break; instead of manually encoding the string yourself, send it to the server using a form and a text area with return/enter inserted line breaks, then it will work.

Comment: @Deadalos:Qoute : Origenally i send: test\ntest to the server and recieved the same line back test\ntest, wich resulted in a json.parse stripping out the backslash: testntest

This is without me manuelly double escaping it.
So as you can json.parse removes the backslash than. :(
Edit: this is with a text area return/enter

Comment: @DDaems It won't alert me unless you spell my name correctly.  I only knew you responded to be because I'm checking this question every now and again.  As to the server-side generation, we'd need to see that code.

Comment: Ok it looks like the problem is serverside. after some additional testing. Trying to send \ and \n literal and with return/enter i came to the conclusion that the server seems to remove the backslash at return/enter.
Stupid from me that i didn't test this earlier.

Anyway thank you sincerly for your answers they where verry helpfull. Sinds i did not know that adding the backslash clientside to the return/enter would result in it being read as literal.

Comment: @Daedalus Thanks i did not know, that this would notify you.
The serverside code is written in C and isn't written or maintained by myself. Sinds i lack the knowledge of it. Anyway i made a issue in our repo and forwarded this discussion. Thx!

Answer (score 1):

you can use

replace \n with \r

try this in vim editor

```
%s/\\n/\r/gec
```

Answer (score 0):

If the output is `test\ntest` using a literal `"\\n"` string, instead of newline break, then you should use `/\\n/g` instead of `/\r?\n/g`